# Trouble assigning array slice to unicode value

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, unicode, slice

I am trying to assign a number of entries in a numpy array to a single unicode value (from another array) using slice notation, but as seen in the snippet below, I'm getting back garbage:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([u'America/Los_Angeles']*3)
>>> a
array([u'America/Los_Angeles', u'America/Los_Angeles',
       u'America/Los_Angeles'],
      dtype='<U19')
>>> s = np.zeros(10,dtype=a.dtype)
>>> s
array([u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u''],
      dtype='<U19')
>>> s[0:2] = a[0]
>>> s
array([ u'\uf300\udc41\uf440\udc65\uf080\udc69\ue380\udc61\uf380\udc4c\uef80\udc73\uf340\udc41\uf100\udc67\uf100\udc6cs\uf8ad\ude98\u7ff5\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\ud7bf\udfff\uf77c\udc30',
       u'\uf300\udc41\uf440\udc65\uf080\udc69\ue380\udc61\uf380\udc4c\uef80\udc73\uf340\udc41\uf100\udc67\uf100\udc6cs\uf8ad\ude98\u7ff5\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\ud7bf\udfff\uf77c\udc30',
       u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u''],
      dtype='<U19')
```

When running this with python 2.7.3 and numpy 1.6.2 I had no problem, getting back what I expected:

```
>>> s
array([u'America/Los_Angeles', u'America/Los_Angeles', u'', u'', u'', u'',
       u'', u'', u'', u''],
      dtype='<U19')
```

But this has apparently changed with python 2.7.10 and numpy 1.9.2. I can come up with various ways around this issue, but my question is this: What is the best (most pythonic, fastest, most general) solution to get the results I was expecting?

The context of this is I'm trying to expand a bunch of arrays from an irregular time series into arrays for a regular time series for arrays of a bunch of different types (float, int, unicode, etc.), so I'd prefer to find solutions that work with any type without a lot of 'if isinstance' clauses.

Comment: WIth Python3.4 and numpy 1.8.2, I get your expected `s` (py3 doesn't show the `u`, but it's still `U19`).

Comment: In Py2.7, np 1.9, I get this error with `a[0]`, but not with `a[[0]]` or `a[0].item()`.  In other words when the assigned value is type `np.unicode_`, but not if it is `np.ndarray` or `unicode`.

Comment: Thanks. I've gone with a.item(0); simple and general.

Answer (score 0):

A more compact example of the problem, in PY2.7, numpy 1.9

```
In [126]: s=np.zeros(1,dtype='U10')

In [127]: s[:]=np.unicode_('abc')

In [128]: s
Out[128]: 
array([u'\uf040\udc61c\ua982\udee8'], 
      dtype='<U10')
```

Without the slice, or with a scalar, no problem

```
In [129]: s[0]=np.unicode_('abc')

In [130]: s
Out[130]: 
array([u'abc'], 
      dtype='<U10')

In [131]: s[:]=u'abc'

In [132]: s
Out[132]: 
array([u'abc'], 
      dtype='<U10')
```

Or with a smaller `s`, I can look at individual bytes with a view:

```
In [154]: s=np.zeros(1,dtype='U3')

In [155]: s[:]=np.unicode_('abc')

In [156]: s
Out[156]: 
array([u'\uf040\udc61c\ua982\udcd0'], 
      dtype='<U3')

In [157]: s.view('U1')
Out[157]: 
array([u'\uf040\udc61', u'c', u'\ua982\udcd0'], 
      dtype='<U1')

In [158]: s.view('S1')
Out[158]: 
array(['a', '', 'b', '', 'c', '', '', '', '\xd0', '\x08', 'G', '\xb7'], 
      dtype='|S1')

In [159]: s.view('S12')
Out[159]: 
array(['a\x00b\x00c\x00\x00\x00\xd0\x08G\xb7'], 
      dtype='|S12')

In [176]: np.array(u'abc').view('S12')
Out[176]: 
array('a\x00\x00\x00b\x00\x00\x00c', 
      dtype='|S12')
```

It feels like the kind of issue that's been raised before, either here or as numpy bug.  But I haven't found it yet.  Maybe this task of assigning one array value to a slice in another is unusual, especially when working with unicode strings in Py2.